# How to make a dictionary within a dictionary in MySQLPython?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, tuples

I have the below code:

```
import MySQLdb  
import sys
import pprint

connect = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.8.2.3", port=3377, user = "root",  db="data1")
with connect:

    cur = connect.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT familynames,names FROM data1.files")

    rows = cur.fetchall()
pprint.pprint(rows)
```

I want to create a big dictionary which has "family names" as key and "names" as the value.Further, the value of the big dict(names), should again be a dict itself with key=names and value= number of identical names under the same family name.

I have tried the DictCursor  function of MySQLPython but it is not capable of creating dict within dict.

I also have tried to make a loop over each item of the big dict to split and create another smaller dict(for values of the big dict) but since the returned result of the cur.execute is a Tuple that is not possible as well.

Can someone help me in this regards?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some processing to get that structure. I'd use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get your rows grouped by family name, then a [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to create the inner mapping you need.

`groupby` requires that you sorted the data, so the query needs a `ORDER BY` clause too:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import pprint

import MySQLdb  

familynames = {}

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.8.2.3", port=3377, user="root",  db="data1")
with connection:
    cur = connect.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT familynames, names FROM data1.files ORDER BY familynames")

    for familyname, names in groupby(cur, key=itemgetter(0)):
        familynames[familyname] = Counter(row[1] for row in names)

pprint.pprint(familynames)
```

The `groupby` function groups the rows on the first element of each row (the `familynames` column), so looping over the `names` iterable will only yield rows where `familynames` has the same value.

We then feed the names (second column in each row) to the `Counter()`, which results in `name` keys with a count for each name as the value.

Comment: Thank you for the help.The problem with the above code is that the counter is only counting its key, so basically the number of the counter is always 1. What I want to see is how many times I get same names with one family name(see below):for instance:

Comment: {Nickelson:{sam:2
            Jack:5
            Joe:10
            Wiliam:1}
Gabrielii: {Maria:2 
     Sami:3}}

Comment: @user2058811: `names` is not the name then? If the second column contains `sam`, `Jack`, `Joe`, etc. then the Counter will count those just like you want.

Comment: yes 'names' is name like sam,Jack etc. but now the code only count number of Sam s not the number of Sam s with Nickelson family name

Comment: @user2058811: No, the code groups rows by family name, that is what `groupby(..., key=itemgetter(0))` does. It groups rows by the *first* column (so `row[0]`).

Comment: @user2058811: I am assuming your query returns rows with `('Family name', 'first name')`, where family name has to be an *exact* match.

Comment: @user2058811: Can you add a few rows example data to your question?

Comment: No unfortunatly I am writing the code on another computer which does not have internet connection on it.

Comment: @user2058811: Even a made-up sample would do. Invent names, as long as it represents the actual patterns it's fine.

Comment: @user2058811: I've tested this locally now and provided the query returns `('familyname', 'firstname')` rows then `firstname` values are counted per `familyname` correctly.